# How to write debug info on screen?

Tags: codeception

I'm writing a test that's not working like I expect.

I need to use some grabbers and then dump to the screen while test is running.

How I can do this ?
How do echo, NOT how user grabber; I'm able to use grabbers but I don't know how to echos while test is running.

Comment: There is no specific command to print to screen / terminal while running a test.

Checkout this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873723/printing-debug-output-to-console-in-codeception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific command to print to screen / terminal while running a test.

I do the following:

```
$I->see($I->grabTextFrom('#myelement'));
```

This way I can at least dump the contents of a element.

Check this out.  I haven't tried this one yet, but looks promising

[Printing debug output to console in Codeception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873723/printing-debug-output-to-console-in-codeception)

Answer (score 8):

Today I've found that in Codeception v2.01 there is a new method that allows you to print to screen.

```
<?php
codecept_debug($I->grabTextFrom('#name'));
?>
```

add the --debug flag to your command you use to run your tests with. eg.

```
php codecept.phar run --debug --steps acceptance
```

Comment: Is there anyway to suppress the header responses in debug mode? e.g. [Response 200] ... ect